# How to intercept special IEEE 802.15.4 frames on OpenThread?

Tags: openthread

I'm new to openthread and got a minimal Thread network running on two Makerdiary USB dongles based on nRF52840. Now I'd like to intercept special IEEE 802.15.4 frames and process them separately, e.g. from an energy harvesting switch. The MAC header looks like this:

- Frame Control: 0x0801 (use short addresses)
- Sequene Number: 1 byte
- Address field: 0xffffffff (short destination address and pan id)
- Source address and pan id are not included

How do I install a callback to intercept these frames and pass all others on to openthread?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way is to hook into the nRF52840 radio driver [where radio frames are received and passed to OpenThread](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/f60a5295fcc7a3ab55b5877052b201e5bd240efd/examples/platforms/nrf528xx/src/radio.c#L661).

Comment: Seems that I can set a callback with otLinkSetPcapCallback() in link.h. I'll try this